# substring extraction with specific format

Tags: python, substring

I have a string which contains a substring with the next format:
it starts with `i_` or `o_` prefix and ends with `,` comma.

How can I extract such string?

For example:

```
string = 'input  [89:0]     i_gth_rxdata,'
```

I need `i_gth_rxdata`

Answer (score 4):

```
my_string = 'input  [89:0]     i_gth_rxdata,'
import re
print re.findall(r'[io]_.*?(?=,)', my_string)
# ['i_gth_rxdata']
```

You can see how that RegEx works, [in this online demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ8iM9)

```
[io]_.*?(?=,)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TukbZEEwaM8EAo4F)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: import re

In [7]: text = 'input [89:0] i_gth_rxdata,'

In [9]: re.search(r'([io]_.*),', text).group(1)
Out[9]: 'i_gth_rxdata'
```

`.*` will match greedily until the *last* comma found. If you want the pattern to match until the *first* comma found, use
`r'([io]_.*?),'`.

Here is an example which shows the difference:

```
In [15]: re.search(r'([io]_.*),', 'input [89:0] i_gth_rxdata, 1,').group(1)
Out[15]: 'i_gth_rxdata, 1'

In [16]: re.search(r'([io]_.*?),', 'input [89:0] i_gth_rxdata, 1,').group(1)
Out[16]: 'i_gth_rxdata'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = 'input [89:0] i_gth_rxdata,'
>>> import re
>>> obj = re.search(r'(i_|o_).*,', s)
>>> obj.group()
'i_gth_rxdata,'
```